# Can I disable an input field inside an embedded Calendly iframe with vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, iframe, calendly

I have an embedded calendly iframe in my website and I am prefilling it's inputs with predefined data which is vital for later API fetching that I am doing so I do not want to let anyone change the prefilled email form, I tried with `setInterval` to check if the element is present and disable it but it appears that `document.getElementsByName` is unable to detect it. Why? Is is a browser security limitation?

Comment: Unless you control that page, you cannot run custom JS inside an iframe.

Comment: @PrerakSola I control the page but it seems that it could not detect the element when it appears on the second step after the time slot selection

Comment: No, I meant the page in the iframe. So, calendly in this case.

Comment: @PrerakSola as you might have guessed, no.... :) thank you very much